# Libgdx Gradle setup - Intellij idea not creating Libraries for Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I setup libgdx using libgdx setup UI created gradle file and imported it using Intellij Idea
http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3336

For desktop/core - Intellij has created all libraries referring to gradle downloaded jar files properly [Image 1]

For Android - Intellij has not created any libraries referring to downloaded android specific jar files [Image 2]
  In gradle cache i can see it has downloaded the android jars  (eg gdx-backend-android-1.4.1.jar) but Intellij has not created Libraries for it

So Intellij is not able to recognise any android/gdx classes like this in AndroidLauncher.java (ie red squiggles)

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;    
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
```

Please clarify why for Android Intellij has not created libraries

[image: Desktop]

[image: Android]

Comment: did you try 'gradlew cleanIdea idea' from the main project commandline?

Comment: That worked. But that removes gradle integration to libgdx. Means from then onwards one has to manually handle all further dependencies at compile time/deployment time etc

Comment: No it shouldn't. I don't use Intellij. You should always be able to use 'gradlew desktop:run' or 'gradlew android:installDebug android:run' from the commandline from your main project. Doesn't have anything to do with building through Eclipse or Intellij. If you're building through Intellij it should work after doing 'gradlew idea'

Comment: Thanks !. One more manual change was required after that in Intellij. Manually change sdk for Android project to 'Android sdk' (instead of jdk). Now from intellij i am even able to build and run to Android emulator !